# JUnit Category - how to avoid code duplication

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Let's say I have two test classes annotated with proper categories:

```
@Category({CategoryA.class})
public class A {
   ...
}
```

and

```
@Category({CategoryB.class})
public class B {
   ...
}
```

which share common codebase and differ only in 1 line of test method.
What would be the best approach to make this code better?
For example, if I use only one class:

```
@Category({CategoryA.class, CategoryB.class})
public class AB {
   ...
}
```

Is there any way to determine category in runtime and add simple *if* statement?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't have an abstract class which does most of the work, then two extending classes and have different `@Category` annotations?  Something like:

```
public abstract class ABParent {
    protected abstract void thingThatsDifferent();
}

@Category(CategoryA.class)
public class A extends ABParent {
    @Override
    protected void thingThatsDifferent() {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}

@Category(CategoryB.class)
public class B extends ABParent {
    @Override
    protected void thingThatsDifferent() {
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course I thought about it, but that requires to have 3 classes instead of 1, just to implement this very simple logic

Comment: Well `Categories` is a suite which doesn't dynamically determine the `@Category`.  You could extend this class and make it do so.  But I don't think 'number of classes' should be a metric you concern yourself with when coding personally.

Comment: Also, the `@Category` annotation can go on individual test methods, not just the class (provided the class isn't a `Parameterized` junit test.